# Can Visual C++ check for mismatched prototype and implementation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2013

Can the VC compiler warn if it cannot find an implementation of a prototype?

Example (notice mismatching params):

```
// calcSomething.h
int calcSomething(
    int    year,
    int    month,
    int    day,
    int    hour,
    int    minute,
    int    second
);
```

and

```
// calcSomething.cpp
int calcSomething(
    int    year,
    int    month,
    int    day
) 
{
  // ... implementation
}
```

Update: Apparently G++ has a switch called `-Wmissing-declarations` which I think might be along the lines of what I need, but obviously for VC++.

Comment: these are two different functions. No compiler can know you wanted them to be one.

Comment: Strictly yes, but through convention of the h/.cpp file it is pretty clear the relationship. Perhaps the compiler can be told it expects every prototype to have an implemenation?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: No, but it can tell that the one with a definition had no prior declaration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Schneider: doing such a assumptions for one case would ruin much more other cases

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Yes, it does. If you declare `int foo(int)` then define `int foo(char)` (when you really meant to define `int foo(int)`), and your compiler warns on no prior declaration, then this mistake is caught. In the typical model where you declare once and define once, the warning is perfect to solve the OP's problem, because in that scenario declaring _never_ and defining once, is an unintentional occurence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: what if I want to import `int foo(int)` and define `int fot(char)`? Is this something compiler should me warn about?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Why not? If it was intentional, you would likely have declared _both_ of them. (This falls apart a little for file-local functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the answer is no.  The MSVC compiler does not have an option equivalent to G++'s -Wmissing-declarations.

[Command line options by category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

These two are totally different functions, according to the C++ language rules.

The compiler should react in the same way as if the name of the first function was `calcSomething` and the name of the second one was `calcSomeOtherThing`.

In particular, the function you declared in the header will be undefined, since it has no implementation. Any code which calls it will not compile and link. It is not possible to make an executable which calls a function which was never defined. The compiler doesn't know what to do when the function is called.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any known way to reduce the chance of the header and implementation getting out of sync at compile time?

Comment: @Schneider actually, you will get linker error once you will try to use calcSomething from calcSomething.h.

Comment: -1: Didn't this answer miss the point? The OP knows all this: he's asking how to get the compiler to spot the mistake, by warning that the overload with a definition was not declared prior.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If he wanted that, he should have verbalized it.